# Python help (computer guess number)

Tags: python

I'm learning how to program in Python and I found 2 tasks that should be pretty simple, but the second one is very hard for me.

Basically, I need to make a program where computer guesses my number. So I enter a number and then the computer tries to guess it. Everytime it picks a number I need to enter `Lower` or `Higher`. I don't know how to do this. Could anyone advise me on how to do it?

For example (number is 5):
computer asks `10?`
I write `Lower`
computer asks `4?`
I write `Higher`

Program:
I already made a program which automatically says `Higher` or `Lower` but I want to input `Lower` or `Higher` as a user.

```
from random import randit
number = int(input("Number? "))

attempts = 0
guess = 0

min = 0
max = 100

while guess != number:
  guess = randint(min,max)
  print(guess,"?")

  if guess < number:
    print("Higher")
    min = guess
  elif guess > number:
    print("Lower")
    max = guess

   attemps += 1

print("I needed", attempts, "attemps")
```

Comment: You will need to make an input for your answer `answer = input("High/Low? ")` then instead of doing your if statements as `if guess < number:`, you just need to change it to `if answer == 'High':`

Comment: but if i remove if guess < number than program will not compare computer's number with one i entered

Comment: You are missing a colon in your `while` statement.

Comment: Since inside your compare for Low or High, you set either the min of the max to the guess, it will keep getting closer and closer to the number. You while loop will then exit once it is equal to the number. You request was to take away the computer's compare, and now you would be doing the comparison as a human, which is what you are doing by inputting High or Low.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to put in a case for if it doesn't match you input, also I think you need a case for when the guess finally equals the number, you may want to allow an input for "Found it!" or something like that.

```
from random import randint
number = int(input("Number? "))

attempts = 0
guess = 0

min = 0
max = 100

while guess != number:
  guess = randint(min,max)
  print(guess,"?")

  answer = str(input("Higher/Lower? "))

  if answer == 'Higher':
    min = guess
  elif answer == 'Lower':
    max = guess

  attempts += 1

print("I needed", attempts, "attempts")
```

Comment: Actually, just thought, you can solve the "Found it" case by moving the guess to the bottom of the loop, and doing a priming input before the loop starts, above the while.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randit 

attempts = 0
guess = 0 
min = 0
max = 100
while guess != number: 
  number = int(input("Number? ")) 
  guess = randint(min,max)
  print(guess,"?") 
  if guess < number:
     print("Higher") 
     min = guess 
  elif guess > number:
      print("Lower") 
      max = guess
  attemps += 1 
print("I needed", attempts, "attemps")
```

problem is your using a loop but inputting value once at start of app . just bring input inside the while statement hope this help

Comment: You don't want to input a new number each iteration of the loop, you want to input a new guess. If you input a new number, then your High/Low responses don't mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

print('choos a number in your brain and if guess is true enter y else any key choose time of guess: ')

print("define the range (A,B) :")
A = int(input("A: "))
B = int(input("B: "))
time = int(input("time:"))

while time != 0:
    ran = randint(A, B)
    inp = input(f"is this {ran} ?")
    time -= 1
    if inp == "y":
        print("bla bla bla computer wins!")
        break
    print("NOPE!")
    if time == 0:
        print("computer game over!")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import *

number = int(input("Number? "))

attempts = 0
guess = 0

min = 0
max = 100
attemps =0
guess = randint(min,max)
while guess != number:
    userInput=input(str(guess)+"?")
    if userInput.lower()=="lower":
        max=guess
    elif userInput.lower()=="higher":
        min=guess
    attemps += 1
    guess = randint(min,max)

print("I needed", attemps, "attempts to guess ur number ="+str(guess))
```

output:

```
Number? 5
66?lower
63?lower
24?lower
19?lower
18?lower
10?lower
4?higher
9?lower
6?lower
4?higher
I needed 10 attempts to guess ur number =5
```